# SPARQL query to match the entity type from two ttl files

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, wikidata, rdflib

I have a ttl file from Yago, and ttl file contains NER from DBpedia

Examples
Yago ttl files

```
<Jungle_Lord>   rdf:type    <wordnet_oeuvre_103841417> .
<Jungle_Lord>   rdf:type    <wordnet_physical_entity_100001930> .
<Jungle_Lord>   rdf:type    <wordnet_pinball_machine_103941417> .
<Jungle_Lord>   rdf:type    <wordnet_product_104007894> .
```

Now, I have DBpedia entity as

DBpedia url, entity

```
https://dbpedia.org/page/Jungle_Lord, Jungle_Lord
```

I want to match the DBpedia entity Jungle_Lord to Yago file and get all the rdf:type, I tried text matching using pandas but its too slow with many error.

How can we match the entity Jungle_Lord to Yago and get rdf:type?

From, two file, I want to get only matched entity and rdf:type

Comment: not sure if I understand, but you have two input files, one from YAGO which contains triples in Turtle syntax and what is the other? Is it a CSV file or what? How did you get this from where? What does the "entity" column denote?

Comment: @UninformedUser yes, I guess it is a CSV file, The file is generated by extracting entities using DBpedia spotlight

Comment: what is the input text in your example? Did you use the web service of Sportlight? I'm asking, because I'm wondering what the second column in your CSV example is supposed to be.